# Adding attribute to the post.php form tag in wp-admin

Tags: php, forms, html

I need to add a 'novalidate' attribute to the form tag in wp-admin post.php. The post.php code itself does not contain the tag, rendered from elsewhere so wondered where it may be or better yet if possible to add this via the functions.php file?

[image: this is what I need to add in at the end]

Comment: Don't even think about changing anything in wordpress core. It will be useless once you update to newer version. Do it from elsewhere, in the theme or a plugin.

Answer (score 1):

The form is generated in file `wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php`. The relevant code starts at line 410 (WP version 4.0.1). Inside the `<form>` tag an action is fired: `<?php do_action( 'post_edit_form_tag', $post ); ?>` so it should be easy to use this action by hooking some small function to it from functions.php:

```
function post_form_novaidate() {
    echo ' novalidate="novalidate" ';
}
add_action( 'post_edit_form_tag', 'post_form_novaidate' );
```

Didn't test, but should work.

Comment: Add/edit forms for taxonomies follow the same convention: actions `${tax}_term_new_form_tag` and `${tax}_term_edit_form_tag` target the middle of `<form>` tag. It's unfortunate we can't add anything to CSS classes though ...

Comment: @PetrCibulka If you want to target it via CSS you can add an individual attribute (`echo ' data-myval="value" '`), which you then target via CSS attribute selector (`form[data-myval]` or `form[data-myval="value"]`)

Comment: Yes, that is what I currently do.

Comment: Confirming that this works.  I needed to add autocomplete="off" to the form cause I'm loading some super custom stuff!